# Seamlessly replace a keyboard input key sequence

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom, abbrev

I need something like [abbrev](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), just without any extra spaces, including spaces which trigger the replacement. I experimented with keyboard shortcuts, like this:

```
;;(general-auto-unbind-keys)
(global-set-key (kbd "H H") "---~")
(global-set-key (kbd "H H J") "~---")
(global-set-key (kbd "J J") "~---~")
```

It replaces every H, whereas I need double H (HH, uppercase only) as a trigger. I tried different shortcut descriptions; unfortunately, this is my best result. Ideally, I want also a timeout (if the second H is lagging, business as usual), and the replacement to be enabled for *.tex files only. Is there a way?

Actually I use Doom Emacs with evil mode.

UPD:

This one is unusable in a different way:

```
(map!
 "H H" "---~"
 "H J" "~---"
 "J J" "~---~"
 )
```

It firmly locks down and waits for the second key, which isn't what I need.

As a matter of fact, this is the vim script code I'm struggling to recreate:

```
inoremap HH ---~
inoremap HJ ~---
inoremap JJ ~---~
```

Comment: You could just use "H J" for the middle combination, to avoid a common prefix.

Comment: Yes, but I have to make it work first, just for two characters. At present it fires right from the first character.

Comment: Have you made `H` a prefix key?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't yet learned the ropes.

Comment: Well, that's probably what `map!` did and you didn't want that, so no loss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution meets all my requirements. The [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/zwmgf6/how_can_i_make_abbreviations_expand_instantly/). Special thanks to Tyler, who prompted me in the right direction.

```
;; Instant abbreviations for LaTeX,
;; English and Cyrillic.
;;
;; In case no expansion is needed, example: (H C-S-q H) results in HH.
(defun abbrev-or-insert ()
  (interactive)
  (self-insert-command 1)
  (expand-abbrev))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'expand-abbrev nil t)

(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
  '(
    ("HH" "---~" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("РР" "---~" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("HJ" "~---" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("РО" "~---" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("JJ" "~---~" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("ОО" "~---~" nil :case-fixed nil :count 0)
    ("LL" "\\ldots{}" nil :case-fixed t :count 0)
    ("ДД" "\\ldots{}" nil :case-fixed t :count 0)
    )
  :regexp (regexp-opt '("HH" "РР" "HJ" "РО" "JJ" "ОО" "LL" "ДД") t))

(global-set-key (kbd "H") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "Р") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "J") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "О") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "L") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "Д") 'abbrev-or-insert)
```

Comment: Actually it works without `(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'expand-abbrev nil t)` just fine. Maybe the innards of Doom Emacs supply it. Anybody in the know is welcome :)

Comment: If you use `abbrev-or-insert`, you need the `global-set-key` code, but you don't need the `post-self-insert-hook`. On the other hand, if you use `post-self-insert-hook` you shouldn't need `abbrev-or-insert` or `global-set-key`

Comment: @Tyler Could you be more specific? It's very interesting, but hopelessly cryptic.

Comment: You solution uses two different answers, either of which should work on its own. There's the code that comes from my answer, which should be all you need (although I don't fully understand your comment under my answer with a problem). The other approach should only require the single line `(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'expand-abbrev nil t)`, as well as the `(define-abbrev-table ..)`. If you use the post-self-insert-hook, you shouldn't need my function or the global-set-key code.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you're after:

```lisp
(defun abbrev-or-insert ()
  (interactive)
  (self-insert-command 1)
  (expand-abbrev))

(define-global-abbrev "HH" "---~")
(define-global-abbrev "JJ" "~---~")
(define-global-abbrev "JH" "~---")

(global-set-key (kbd "H") 'abbrev-or-insert)
(global-set-key (kbd "J") 'abbrev-or-insert)
```

With this approach, you can't use three letter combos that repeat a two-letter combo. i.e., if you define `HH` to be one abbrev, you can't also use `HHJ` as a different abbrev`.

Comment: Thanks! There are two kinks, so far: (1) it takes a workaround, like entering `hh` and then uppercase it manually, to insert `HH`, for instance, if you really need actual `HH` for some reason, because it remembers the first `H` indefinitely; (2) it does not respect non-English characters. For me it's essential to keep the abbreviation across different layouts.

Comment: 1) you could also to `H C-Q H`, to enter `HH` without forcing an expansion. But yes, in general you'll want to use combos that don't get used often or ever.
2) I don't know what this means, I only use an English keyboard. You should be able to add bindings for different characters in different layouts? I'm not sure how that works though

Comment: As a matter of fact, your *abbrev* solution accepts non-english characters. It's the key-chord approach, otherwise very satisfactory, that's stubborn :)

Comment: There's a wrinkle: `---~---~aaaHH ---~---~aaaHH ---~`. After any input it takes a space to put things back to rights.

Comment: Will you please have a look at the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

The thing I so badly wanted is the [Key Chord](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/key-chord). The motion even has its proper name, come to think of it.

```
;; Mapping a pair of simultaneously pressed keys to a command or
;; mapping the same key being pressed twice in quick
;; succession to a command. Such bindings are called "key chords".
(key-chord-mode 1)
(key-chord-define-global "HH" "---~")
(key-chord-define-global "HJ" "~---")
(key-chord-define-global "JJ" "~---~")
```

Comment: Most unfortunately, it won't work with non-English characters.